# Javascript - simplify duplicate functions down to only one master function

Tags: javascript

How can i just have only 1 function that creates the objects instead of duplicating the function for each?  Yes, I'm a newbie.  I use a php template that loads 8 of these with a lot more variables but when I try to pass the vars as arguments through only one function, I always get some sort of error.  I know this has something to do with perhaps constructor functions, or some other method??

```
<!--this uses howler audio js to create sound objects and control them-->
<!--however i don't think you need to be familiar with it - the question below is mainly about JS functions-->
<script src="https://viewescape.com/test_howler/dist/howler.js"></script>


<script>


// these are gathered from a php file and populated
var HowlSoundA;
var HowlSoundB;
var soundA = soundA.mp3;
var soundAvolume = 0.5;
var soundB = soundB.mp3;
var soundBvolume = 0.5;
// etc.

// create soundA object
function playSoundA()
    {

        HowlSoundA = new Howl({
            src: ['soundA.mp3'],
            volume: soundAvolume,
        });
    
    }

// create soundB object
function playSoundB()
    {

        HowlSoundB = new Howl({
            src: ['soundB.mp3'],
            volume: soundBvolume,
        });
    
    }
    
// create the sounds
playSoundA();
playSoundB();

// play the sounds
HowlSoundA.play();
HowlSoundB.play();


</script>
```

======== This added after original post ========

Here's an attempt to resolve but I'm getting undefined:

```
<script src="https://viewescape.com/test_howler/dist/howler.js"></script>

<script>

var soundA, soundB;

// create sounds
createSound(soundA,'soundA.mp3',0.2);
createSound(soundB,'soundB.mp3',0.3);


function createSound(soundID,filename,volume)
    {

            soundID = new Howl({
            src: ['filename'],
            volume: volume,
        });
    
    }
    

// play the sounds
// SoundA.play();
// SoundB.play();

console.log(soundA);
console.log(soundB);

</script>
```

Comment: Please post the code that generates the error, and include the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use all those independent variables. Whatever the data's coming from in PHP, use `json_encode` to pass everything at once in a single JSON string - then you can parse the JSON in the JavaScript and iterate over the array of objects.

For example, you could interpolate the JSON into a `<script>` tag, and then select that tag and parse it:

```
<script type="application/json" class="soundData">
[{"src":"soundA.mp3", "volume":0.5},{"src":"soundB.mp3", "volume":0.5}]
</script>
<script>
const jsonFromServer = document.querySelector('.soundData').textContent;
const allSounds = JSON.parse(jsonFromServer);

// Create the sounds
const howlSounds = allSounds.map(sound => new Howl(howlSound));

// Play the sounds
for (const howlSound of howlSounds) {
  howlSound.play();
}
</script>
```

If the data in PHP isn't originally structured as an array of objects with `src` and `volume` properties, either change the logic in the PHP so that it does, or change the JavaScript logic to transform the data structure as needed.

Comment: Wow, ok I'm going to try to get my head around this.  It's beyond comprehension related to my original question, and I'm sure it's the 'complete' way to do it.  Thanks!  Stay tuned.